# Relation between orthogonality and linear independece of a set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Does it make sense to ask a necessary and sufficient condition for an orthogonal set to be linearly independent? It is easy to prove that if $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ is an orthogonal set, then it is linearly independent. However, the converse is not true.

I found the above question in this [textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=kPDtAp3UZtIC&pg=PA284&dq=What%20is%20the%20necessary%20and%20sufficient%20condition%20for%20an%20orthogonal%20set%20to%20be%20linearly%20independent?&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCo9yBjePdAhUSna0KHTewDvoQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=What%20is%20the%20necessary%20and%20sufficient%20condition%20for%20an%20orthogonal%20set%20to%20be%20linearly%20independent%3F&f=false), exercise 8.

Comment: What about a zero vector?

Comment: You mean, $n=1$ and $\{v_1\}=\{0\}$?

Comment: No, I mean one of vectors $v_{i}$ is $\vec{0}.$

Comment: As Maam was trying to point out, an orthogonal set can contain the zero vector, in which case it is not independent. It's not quite true that any orthogonal set is independent... look carefully at your proof of this not-quite-fact and you see  a detail you overlooked.

Comment: You are right. But since we talked about linearly independence, I kinda assume that all the vectors are nonzero.

Comment: If one of the vectors is zero, we will not have linearly independence.